# Finding out if a series of job emails from the same person are a scam or a way of tracking/phishing?

Tags: email, user-tracking, scam

I'm Indian, and have received a third job email from a Canadian "Co-founder and COO". I'm not even actively job searching.

1. He hasn't mentioned how he got my mail id or why I'm the right fit
   for the job.
2. Google's "secret sauce" shows the yellow icon that probably indicates
   the email is not spam.  [image]
3. The emails have images which GMail has hidden for safety reasons, and
   I was careful not to click on the "Display images below" link.
4. His email signature contains a "We're hiring" link that leads to:
   https://hiscompany-dot-yamm-track.appspot.com/Redirect?ukey=1wQLKWIOnoiYyfDopetkntTdf7QKeYeABTwjUQf1vzCU-551884202&key=YAMMID-12656006&link=https%3A%2F%2Fhiscompany.io%2Fjoin-hiscompany%2F. I didn't click it.

I ignored the first two emails because they almost exclusively speak of immigration, permanent residency and Canadian citizenship.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any danger in just replying to find out if the offer is genuine? It doesn't follow the [typical scam email pattern](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&hs=lHN&ei=ChluXL2EF8TorQH82b24BQ&q=automated%20job%20offer%20email%20scams%20immigration&oq=automated%20job%20offer%20email%20scams%20immigration&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4532.6249..6459...0.0..0.268.2393.0j6j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.b5M9x0w2OQ4), but could just be an improvisation. This degree of persistence could also point to jobs that exploit people in exchange for Canadian citizenship. Perhaps even another [University of Farmington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Farmington).
2. In case it's a scam, I believe the typical modus operandi would be to send a malicious PDF. I wonder if simply replying to him or clicking any of the links in his email would give him enough of info about my computer or phone to compromise it?

For the reference of anyone who receives similar emails:

**Email 1: Feb 10, 2019**
Subject: A Unique Machine Learning Opportunity in Canada

> Hi MyName,
>
> My name is HisName and I’m the Head of Operations at HisCompany.  We
>   are a Canadian company currently hiring top-tier Software Engineers,
>   Data Engineers, and Data Scientists.  Our employees are based in
>   Canada, and they are paired with U.S.-based start-ups on an exclusive,
>   long-term basis. By doing this, we are combining the wonderful quality
>   of life and immigration system that Canada offers with the technical
>   opportunities of top Silicon Valley start-ups.
>
> Beyond offering high-quality jobs, HisCompany also offers full-service
>   immigration.  We have partnered with the Canadian government to get
>   successful candidates into Canada in as little as four weeks, and they
>   each have a clear path to permanent residency status or Canadian
>   citizenship.
>
> If any of this sounds interesting, it would be great to hear back from
>   you.
>
> Thanks MyName,
>
> -HisName
>
> HisName Surname Co-Founder & COO HisCompany (We're Hiring) Canada: 
>   403.xxx.xxxx USA:  650.xxx.xxxx

**Email 2: Feb 14, 2019**
Subject: A Unique Machine Learning Opportunity in Canada

> Hi MyName,
>
> I just wanted to follow up on the email I sent a few days ago about
>   Machine Learning opportunities we have at HisCompany.  I'm not sure if
>   you've ever considered relocation to Canada, but it is easier than
>   most people are aware.  Our immigration team can usually get an
>   engineer (and their family) immigration visas in as little as four
>   weeks.
>
> I'd be really excited to tell you more and answer any questions you
>   might have, so if you're interested please let me know with a quick
>   reply.
>
> Thanks again MyName,
>
> -HisName
>
> HisName Surname Co-Founder & COO HisCompany (We're Hiring) Canada: 
>   403.xxx.xxxx USA:  650.xxx.xxxx

**Email 3: Today**
Subject: Reconnecting with you MyName

> Hi MyName,
>
> Just in case my last message ended up in your spam folder, I wanted to
>   reach out again.  I'd love to take some time to tell you about some of
>   the great Machine Learning opportunities for which we are hiring.
>
> I'd love to have a quick chat to talk about this in more detail. 
>   Would you be available in the next week to have a quick call?
>
> Here is a link to our website if you want more information -
>   https://www.HisCompany.io/
>
> Until next time MyName,
>
> -HisName
>
> HisName Surname   Co-Founder & COO   HisCompany (We're Hiring)
>   Canada:  403.xxx.xxxx   USA:  650.xxx.xxxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This looks like a scam to me.**

The Link to "their recruiting-site" is really a red flag for me. Not explaining the reason, why they reach out exactly to you and how they got your contact is also not professional at all.

One possible scam scheme could work like this:

1. Send E-Mails.
2. Send Follow-Up-Emails until you believe it's legit.
3. Make some promises about a great job and a permanent residency in Canada.
4. Request some money for the paperwork (visa, work permit, etc.)
5. Find more reasons, why they need some more money or information
6. repeat #4 and #5 until you give up

However there might be numerous other schemes, that could allow him to make money, gain information or your trust.

**Edit:** If you were to click the links or load the images in the mail, he'd probably able to identify your OS, Browser, Browser-Plugins, rough location (based on IP), validate your e-mail address. This can, in rare cases, be sufficient to successfully compromise your system, depending on patches, etc.